# Return List on Basis of Condition in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my list in which I am sending itemIds for which I am fetching data and returning in an arraylist , now my requirement is if name exists and datas value is data then only show the list , else remove that object from the list, And this is I am trying to do and it is very much possible that in particular object , name and datas key might not exist in that case I am getting error such as but I dont want this error I want to return data in condition is fulfilled if no object key exists then return empty list .

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "status": "Failed",
    "message": "Error : Cannot invoke \"String.equals(Object)\" because \"datas\" is null",
    "data": null,
    "success": false
}
```

Code for fetching list :-

```
 @Override
        public List<Item> getcollectionfromapi(List<String> itemids) throws Exception {
            List<Item> itemCollection = itemRepository.findById(itemids);
            ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCollection.size(); i++) {
                String name = itemCollection.get(i).getProduct().getName();
                String datas = itemCollection.get(i).getData();
                boolean equalsIgnoreCase = datas.equals("Data");
                if (name.length() > 0 && equalsIgnoreCase == true) {
                    arrayList.addAll(itemCollection);
                } else {
                    itemCollection.remove(i);
                    arrayList.addAll(itemCollection);
                }
            }
            return arrayList;
    
        }
```

sample JsonList

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "datas": "data",
    "product": {
      "name": "Transport",
      "value":"1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "product": {
      "value":"2"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "datas": "Data",
    "product": {
      "name": "Transport",
      "value":"3"
    }
  }
]
```

After applying Condition it should return

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "datas": "data",
    "product": {
      "name": "Transport",
      "value":"1"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "datas": "Data",
    "product": {
      "name": "Transport",
      "value":"3"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<Item> getcollectionfromapi(List<String> itemids) throws Exception {
                List<Item> itemCollection = itemRepository.findById(itemids);
                ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < itemCollection.size(); i++) {
                    String name = itemCollection.get(i).getProduct().getName();
                    String datas = itemCollection.get(i).getData(); 
//add validation for datas is not null
//add logic what to return if datas is null
                    //boolean equalsIgnoreCase = datas.equals("Data");
                    if (datas != null && name.length() < 0 && datas.equalsIgnoreCase("Data") == false) {
                        itemCollection.remove(i);
                    }
                    arrayList.addAll(itemCollection);
                }
                return arrayList;
        
            }
```

Comment: Its returning data for every id , even the condition is not matched

Answer (score 0):

There is one major problem in your code.
datas.equals("Data");
Instead of this above line you should write this way.
"Data".equals(datas).This way case you will never get null pointer exception.

Moreover you can write your code like this.

```
@Override
    public List<Item> getcollectionfromapi(List<String> itemids) throws Exception {
        List<Item> itemCollection = itemRepository.findById(itemids);
        ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCollection.size(); i++) {
            String name = itemCollection.get(i).getProduct().getName();
            String datas = itemCollection.get(i).getData();
            boolean equalsIgnoreCase = false;
            if(datas != null)
            {
                equalsIgnoreCase = datas.equals("Data");
            }
 //  if (StringUtils.isnotEmpty(name) && equalsIgnoreCase == true) // Use this condition if you have commons-lang3 jar.         
            if (name!=null && !("null".equals(name)) && name.length() > 0 && equalsIgnoreCase == true) {
                arrayList.addAll(itemCollection);
            } else {
                itemCollection.remove(i);
                arrayList.addAll(itemCollection);
            }
        }
        return arrayList;

    }
```

Comment: "Error : Cannot invoke \"String.length()\" because \"name\" is null",

Comment: Add a null check for name as well in if condition. If you are using apach commons lang3 jar then you can use StringUtils.isNotEmpty() method.

Comment: In case where value of name is null , item is not removed from the list

Comment: value as null and object is null are two different things. If value is null then your object is not empty or null hence must be added to the list. Hope I cleared your doubt.

Comment: my condition was when name is equals to null remove that particular jsonobject from the list

Comment: If you want that if name has value as null should not be added to the list then you have to add one more check. I have made changes in the code above.